# static field is unable to be forward referenced in static block but is able to be assigned a value

Tags: java, jvm

Take a look at a test case :

```
public class StaticFieldTest {
    public  static  int A= 1;
    static {
        A=2;
        NAME="AAA";
        //  System.out.println(NAME);  // Can't forward reference
    }
    public  static  String NAME = "Archer";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(NAME);
    }
}
```

The output is `Archer`. 
It is obvious that `NAME="AAA"` is tedious. Why Java allow this sort of  writing?

Comment: `Why Java allow this sort of writing?` What sort of writing? I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Order matters for static initialization. Have a look at this similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8131812/571189)

Comment: I think OP question is not why reference NAME ends with value "Archer" but why NAME reference can't be used in `System.out.println(NAME)` even if its value can be set.

Comment: @Tudor No matter what value the variable `NAME` is assigned, it would be `"Archer"` at last. Thus, To allow to assign a value to variable `NAME` in static block is strange

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the order of initialization

The static initializers and class variable initializers are executed in textual order. In your example, static block precedes static variable assignment. If the order is switched, the answer will be different.

When a class is instantiated (object is created), **Instance Variables** are initialized and then **Contructor** is called.

Comment: static variables are initialized in static block itself.

Comment: Yes, I meant any statements inside static block (including assignment statements if any) will be executed and then static variables with definition/assignment statements will be executed after static block.

Comment: Internally, static variable assignments are initialized in the static block itself

Comment: Not necessarily, only if the reference to the static variable is done in the static block itself. According to JLS, "The static initializers and class variable initializers are executed in textual order.", meaning in the order they are referenced in the code.

Comment: You still didn't get my point. variable declaration tells about how the variable should be handled. assignment is an instruction to be executed so is executed inside the block of code. so if you do this: `public static int a = 10;` then the byte would be like this: `public static int a; static { a = 10; }`.

Comment: Sure I understand what you are talking about is difference between variable incarnation and assignment. Still my point is if you don't write a static block then java does not create a block for you so that it can initialize the variable.

Comment: then how can it initialize the static variable?

Comment: Just like any other variable, Atomically create the variable and assign the value except the static variables will be created and assigned a value while the class is loaded

Comment: To do that, compiler needs to generate a code right. where will it be placed? that's why static block comes into picture. read my above example in javap.

Comment: Dude When bytecodes are generated there are no more static blocks it's just sequence of operations (load and store)

Comment: Dude you need to group those operations, think of function, and call it right. that grouping is what i call static block.

Answer (score 0):

They [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.3) suggests that this is in place  "to catch, at compile time, circular or otherwise malformed initializations."

The reason why your `NAME = AAA;` is compilable is that `NAME` is on the left hand side of the statement.

---

[8.3.2.3. Restrictions on the use of Fields during Initialization](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.3)

The declaration of a member needs to appear textually before it is used only if the member is an instance (respectively static) field of a class or interface C and all of the following conditions hold:

- The usage occurs in an instance (respectively static) variable initializer of C or in an instance (respectively static) initializer of C.
- **The usage is not on the left hand side of an assignment.**
- The usage is via a simple name.
- C is the innermost class or interface enclosing the usage.